# Removing users who deleted app from database - iOS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, apn

I currently have a table in a mysql database with all the apn tokens of the users of my iOS app.

Every 24 hours my server runs a script that sends a notification to each user in the table.

I am sure some users are no longer active/have deleted the app and I was wondering if there is a way to identify them/remove them from this table?

The notification involves making a call to a weather api service (which is not free) so I am trying to avoid making unnecessary calls!

Comment: The response from the APNS tells you when a token is no longer valid: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW1

Comment: I actually wasn't fully clear initially - i still do need to make the weather api call if the user does not enable push notifications. So I need to be certain if the user still has the app installed or not

Comment: The only way you know if a user has installed an app is if the push fails.  You should probably register all devices for remote notification. You need the permission to actually have the notification displayed, but you can register and send remote notifications without asking the user for any permission. You could even use a probe "silent push" to check if the app is still installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple doc says if you get a

> 400

http code with

> BadDeviceToken

as reason then

> The specified device token is invalid. Verify that the request
>   contains a valid token and that the token matches the environment.

I check every response from the APN and invalidate/delete bad tokens from my database.

But you still need to do your weather request one more time for each device until its deleted from your DB.

You could send a silent notification before your request to check if the device token is valid, but that would be two notifications for one.

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to add that I've been seeing a response of `410 - The device token is no longer active for the topic` in my testing after I try to send a notification after deleting the app